# Work and time problem . People leaving work one by one and at the same time reducing their rate of doing work.

Tags: word-problem

> Question: A group of $30$ people can complete a job working for $10$ hours a day in
>   $15$ days. The group starts a work. But at the end of every day, starting
>   from the first day, one person leaves the group and the remaining people
>   work for $20$ minutes less on the next day.
>   On which day will the work be completed?
>
> Answer: $29$th day.

Attempted solution:

[image: page 1]
[large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ52p.jpg)

[image: page 2]
[large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sISb4.jpg)

Please help me solve this problem.Please tell me where I have gone wrong. Whether in concept or in calculations....Thank you..

Comment: See here: http://www.examveda.com/a-group-of-30-people-can-complete-a-job-by-working-for-10-hours-a-day-in-15-days-the-group-starts-the-work-but-at-the-end-of-every-9215/

Comment: Yes Sir. Each person works 20 minutes less each day.

Comment: Yes Sir true. " 
 all remaining persons perform at the same rate on a particular day."

Comment: Hm.. the assumption must be wrong. I would need $54$ days, ending up with $-24$ people working.

Comment: @mvw Sir then what should be the assumption according to you?......I have solve the inequality that has been provided by Unwisdom sir. From there as well I get the answer as 53.48 (approximately equal to 54 days).

Comment: The group of remaining people as a whole reduces work by $20$ minutes each day.  See my revised answer. The problem is not stated withou ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed amount of work: 
$$
W 
= 30 \cdot 10 \frac{\text{h}}{\text{d}} \cdot 15 \text{d}
= 4500 \text{h}
$$
Rate of work per person over time: 
$$
r(t) = 10 \frac{\text{h}}{\text{d}}
$$
Active people:
\begin{align}
n(1) &= 30 \\
n(t) &= 30 - (t - 1) = 31 - t
\end{align}
Work done until day $t$, where the group in total works $1/3$ hour less each day:
\begin{align}
W(t) 
&= \sum_{k=1}^t 
\left( 
n(k) \, r(k)- \frac{k-1}{3} \frac{\text{h}}{\text{d}} 
\right) \, 1 \text{d} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^t 
\left( (31 - k) 10 - \frac{1}{3} k + \frac{1}{3} \right) \text{h} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^t 
\left(
\frac{931}{3} - \frac{31}{3} k \right) \text{h} \\
&= 
\left(
\frac{931}{3} \sum_{k=1}^t 1 - \frac{31}{3} \sum_{k=1}^t k \right) \text{h} \\
&= 
\left(
\frac{931}{3} t - \frac{31}{3} \frac{t^2+t}{2} \right) \text{h} \\
&= 
\left( \frac{1831}{6} t - \frac{31}{6} t^2 \right) \text{h} \\
\end{align}
We can now solve the quadratic equation:
$$
-\frac{4500 \cdot 6}{31} 
= t^2 - \frac{1831}{31} t
= \left( t - \frac{1831}{62} \right)^2 - \left( \frac{1831}{62} \right)^2 \iff \\
t = \frac{1831 \pm\sqrt{1831^2 - 4500 \cdot 6 \cdot 4 \cdot 31}}{62} \\
= \frac{1831 \pm \sqrt{4561}}{62} \in \{ 28.44, 30.62  \}
$$

So only $t= 28.44$ makes sense (we have $30$ people, which are all gone after $30$ days), thus we need $29$ days to achieve the $4500$ hours of work.

Comment: Sir  cant the function r(t) be written as r(t)=(10-(t-1)/3) h/d as the rate of doing work decreases each day by 1/3rd hour and solved accordingly. In that case W(t)=Summation (over k=1 to t) [n(k)r(k)]= Summation (over k=1 to t)[(30-(k-1))(10-(k-1)/3)]=Summation (over k=1 to t)(31-k)^2/3.......Sir why I am asking this is because I didnt understand -(k-1)/3 after n(k)r(k) in your answer. Sir please help.

Comment: No, you only get the $29$ days, if you assume that the slowdown is just $(t-1)/3$ and not the larger amount $n(t) (t-1)/3$. The whole group slows down $20$ min per day, not the individuals.

Comment: Ok so so for each passing day after the start  the work reduces by 1/3rd...hence it is subtracted from the original work n(k)r(k). Thanks for explaining it so well.

Comment: But Sir, (k-1)/3 is time ...How do you equate it to work?

Comment: Understood...You are doing it by person hours.....hence the unit is hours....No wonder why German Engineering is famous worldwide!

Answer (score 3):

The job will require $30\times 15\times 10=4500$ person hours.

The number of person hours worked on day $k$ is $(31-k)\times\frac{31-k}{3}$; this is the number of people working times the number of hours worked.

Thus the total work done by day $n$, in person hours is:
$$W(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(31-k)^2}{3}$$.

Your problem is to find the least $n$ such that $W(n)\geq 4500$.

Comment: Your solution has helped me in understanding the concept but as mvw sir has pointed out that the whole group slows down 20 min per day, not each individual. hence (k-1)/3 has to be deducted as he has shown in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use $20$ minutes as time unit. The total work load then is $30\cdot 10\cdot15\cdot 3=13\,500$ units. On day${}_k$ there are $31-k$ people at work, and each of them works during $31-k$ units. After day${}_{30}$ there is nobody left to do any work. The total number of units performed by then is
$$\sum_{k=1}^{30}(31-k)^2=9455<13\,500\ .$$
It follows that the work will not be completed at all.